# Angular $scope function not running

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app that works with every function but this. I get no errors, but this function is never even being executed

```
...
$scope.contact = function(contactID){
        console.log("test");
        for(i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
            if(contacts[i].id == contactID){
                return contacts[i];
            }
        }
    }
  };
...
```

Here is the entire controller:

```
.controller('ContactsCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, Auth, Data, $localStorage, $stateParams) {
    $scope.token = $localStorage.token;
    $scope.tokenClaims = Auth.getTokenClaims();
    $scope.contacts = Data.getApiContacts(
        function(list) {
            $scope.contacts = list;
            $localStorage.contacts = list;
            return list;
        },
        function() {
            $rootScope.error = 'Failed to fetch contacts.';
        }
    );
    $scope.contact = function(contactID) {
        console.log("test");
        for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            if (contacts[i].id == contactID) {
                return contacts[i];
            }
        }
    }
};
})
```

Comment: Lower case  'console.log' and use for in loop.

Comment: What are you using to call the function?

Comment: It was actually a lower case, that was from me typing on my phone. Its part of my controller. All other functions and scope declarations are working just fine. I've updated to show the entire controller

Comment: @brandenwagner check my answer